# word count program in apache pig latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i am a newbie in apache pig and i am unable to figure out how to write the word count program with the below points

a. Read from this input file, input file location should be parameterized in the pig script
c. Perform a word count (word delimiters: space and other pig delimiters like {, },
d. Must ignore comment lines
e. Sort by count (frequent words first)

help will be appreciated.

Comment: And what do you have so far? Reading any file at all? Filtering at least comments?

Comment: If you do a simple search, you should be able to get a lot of examples.After reading those examples you should be able to come up with the first draft of the script.After that if you still have problems, post your input data and the first draft of the script.

Comment: @cricket_007 as i am very much new to pig, and as it project urgent i dont have time to sit and read. I figured out the word count but unable to figure out how to write the script to ignore comments, count delimiter and spaces. In short the script should count everything in the input text file.if you can provide me a generic script that will count words, spaces, commas, delimiters, it will be great. The input file is a pig script itself.

Comment: @VK_217 with little reading i came to know how to count words and it was easy. But i am unable to find functions or trick that will count everything else that is in the input file. File cannot be shared bcz of compliance. If you can i need the generic functions that can count spaces, delimiters, commas, in short everything in the input file. As i said above, thr input file is also a pig script. This scriot should count everything in the script. Its project urgent i dont have time to sit and read

Comment: Pig isn't really meant to do such tasks, as counting characters... not without writing serveral non-Pig UDFs which you can import and run within your Pig scripts. You would have much better luck with Spark as you have full control over the data you are processing. But I suggest you try `LOAD` and `FILTER` on your own, and [edit] the question. If you impose your urgency on us, then you won't get much help, unfortunately because we are busy individuals as well

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.PigServer;


public class idLocal {

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try{
        PigServer pigServer = new PigServer("local");
        runIdQuery(pigServer,"/root/Desktop/FILE/sample.txt");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print(e);
    }
}
public static void runIdQuery(PigServer pigServer,String inputFile) throws IOException{

    pigServer.registerQuery("myinput = load'"+ inputFile +"' as(line);");
    pigServer.registerQuery("words = foreach myinput generate flatten(TOKENIZE(line)) as word;");
    pigServer.registerQuery(" grpd = group words by word;");
    pigServer.registerQuery("cntd = foreach grpd generate group,COUNT(words);");
    pigServer.store("cntd", "id.out");
}
}
```

You try This code must be work.....